# Intellij Error trying to preview from SWING UI DESIGNER, GUI FORM

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea, apple-m1, java-21

i'm having some issues with intellij on Macos.
I've create a new class using swing UI designer but when on the form designer i right-click on the designer and select "Preview" the response is this error:

[image: INTELLIJ ERROR ON PREVIEW].

I'm using Java 21 and the same project on Windows make the preview working correctly.

if I launch the application printing the main panel it works but the preview generate this error.

Does anyone know how to fix it? It's quite complicated and cumbersome to launch the application every time to check the apparence of the graphics design.

The code of the class is the following:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class JTable extends JFrame {
    private javax.swing.JTable table1;
    private JPanel mainPanel;

    public JTable() {
        Object[][] data = {{"Toyota", "Camry", "Sedan"}, {"Honda", "Accord", "Sedan"}, {"Ford", "Mustang", "Coupe"}};
        String[] columnNames = {"Make", "Model", "Type"};
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
        table1.setModel(model);
    }

    public JPanel getMainPanel() {
        return mainPanel;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance to everyone.

I attempted to create a new project and changed the Java version, but the result remains unchanged.

I tried the same on IntelliJ using Windows as the operating system, and it worked there.

Comment: Please see if it works with Java 17 for the project. The current IntelliJ IDEA version runs on a Java 17 version which cannot load classes from higher Java versions to show the preview.

Comment: With java20 or less it works. Is there any way to make it works on java 21? The entire project is based on java 21.

Comment: Probably needs fixing in the IDE. Feel free to report a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA.